# CUDA separable compilation and CMake

Tags: cuda, makefile, cmake, dynamic-linking

I have a large library project that contains both cpp and cu source files. I'd like to compile it in a standalone shared object, but since I have some device functions I decided to split it in a shared object containing the majority of the functions and an archive file containing the device functions only. Here's part of the Makefile I wrote for it - all the (non-template) device functions have been put in the file device.cu:

## Makefile

```
LIB_NAME = libexample.so
CUDA = /usr/local/cuda/include
CXX = g++
CXXFLAGS = -c -O2 -fPIC -Wall -I. -I./code -I./code/header -I$(CUDA)
SOURCES = src1.cpp src2.cpp src3.cpp
OBJECTS = $(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)
NVCC = nvcc
CU_SOURCES = src1_cu.cu src2_cu.cu src3_cu.cu device.cu
CU_OBJECTS = $(CU_SOURCES:.cu=.o)
BUILDDIR = .
VPATH = code/src/common_src code/src/src_CUDA
DEVICE_LINK = dev_link.o
GENCODE_FLAGS := -gencode arch=compute_20,code=sm_20

NVCCFLAGS = -x cu -O2 --compiler-options '-fPIC' $(GENCODE_FLAGS) -I. -I./code -I./code/header -I$(CUDA) -dc 
NVCCLINK = --compiler-options '-fPIC' $(GENCODE_FLAGS) -dlink

all: lib/$(LIB_NAME)

lib/$(LIB_NAME): $(OBJECTS) $(CU_OBJECTS) $(DEVICE_LINK)
    $(CXX) -shared -Wl,-soname,libexample.so $^ -o $@
    ar rcs lib/device.a device.o

%.o: %.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $< -o $@

%.o: %.cu
    $(NVCC) $(NVCCFLAGS) $< -o $@

$(DEVICE_LINK): $(CU_OBJECTS)
    $(NVCC) $(NVCCLINK) $^ -o $@
```

I decided to change my build system and I switched to CMake to produce both Makefiles and Visual Studio projects. It's obvious how to write a working CMakeLists.txt file **without** separable compilation, but I couldn't find a solution that works in my case (I read some proposed solutions here on S.O. but they don't seem to work for me!). Can you help me to write said CMakeLists.txt file? Here's what I did so far:

## CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.10)

# Set Library & project name
set(LIB_NAME example)
project(${LIB_NAME})

message("LIBRARY ${LIB_NAME}")
enable_language(CXX)

# Check if CUDA is installed on this system
find_package(CUDA REQUIRED)

# Set source directories
set(COMMON_SRCS_DIR ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/code/src/common_src)
set(CUDA_SRCS_DIR ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/code/src/src_CUDA)

# Set source files
set(COMMON_SRCS ${COMMON_SRCS_DIR}/src1.cpp
        ${COMMON_SRCS_DIR}/src2.cpp
        ${COMMON_SRCS_DIR}/src3.cpp
)

# Set CUDA device library name
set(DEVICE_LIB "device")

# Set CUDA objects
cuda_compile(SRC1_CU_O ${CUDA_SRCS_DIR}/src1_cu.cu)
cuda_compile(SRC2_CU_O ${CUDA_SRCS_DIR}/src2_cu.cu)
cuda_compile(SRC3_CU_O ${CUDA_SRCS_DIR}/src3_cu.cu)
cuda_compile(DEVICE_CU_O ${CUDA_SRCS_DIR}/device.cu)

# Set header file directories
include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR})
include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/code)
include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/code/header)
include_directories(${CUDA_INCLUDE_DIRS})

# Get CUDA compute capability - contains CUDA_GENCODE define
include(CudaParams.cmake)

# Set include stuff
cuda_include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR})
cuda_include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/code)
cuda_include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/code/header)
cuda_include_directories(${CUDA_INCLUDE_DIRS})

set(CUDA_SEPARABLE_COMPILATION ON)

# Set compiler flags
set(CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS "${CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS} ${CUDA_GENCODE} --compiler-options '-fPIC' -O2")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wall -march=native -O2")

# Generate main target
cuda_add_library(${LIB_NAME} SHARED ${COMMON_SRCS} 
    ${SRC1_CU_O} ${SRC2_CU_O} ${SRC3_CU_O} ${DEVICE_CU_O})
cuda_add_library(${DEVICE_LIB} STATIC ${DEVICE_CU_O})

# Install instructions
INSTALL(TARGETS ${LIB_NAME}
    LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/lib
    ARCHIVE DESTINATION ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/lib
    )
```

As you can see, there's no dev_link.o mention in the CMakeLists.txt file because I simply don't know where I could put it!

Comment: I know this is a very late comment, but: 1. You have a lot of code duplication in your `CMakeListst.txt`, e.g. with headers. 2. Don't explicitly use `cuda_compile` - just have your library depend on `.cu` files. 3. I'm not quite sure what's going wrong when you cmake or build.